# How to get the AUC score per model and for ensemble model in Species Distribution Modeling

Tags: r, auc

I want to get evaluation metric as AUC score per model and for ensemble model for SDM. The distribution modeling has been conducted using BIOMOD2 package in R. With the get_evaluation I am getting values of Testing.data, Cutoff, Sensitivity and Specificity but I would like to have AUC score in a table per model so that I can have a boxplot. I am aware command models_scores_graph provides a graph but I want it in table form. The code till models_score_graph is given below:

```
DataSpecies <- read.csv(system.file("external/species/mammals_table.csv",
                            package="biomod2"), row.names = 1)



myRespName <- 'GuloGulo'

myResp <- as.numeric(DataSpecies[,myRespName])

myRespXY <- DataSpecies[,c("X_WGS84","Y_WGS84")]

myExpl = raster::stack( system.file( "external/bioclim/current/bio3.grd", 
                             package="biomod2"),
                system.file( "external/bioclim/current/bio4.grd", 
                             package="biomod2"), 
                system.file( "external/bioclim/current/bio7.grd", 
                             package="biomod2"),  
                system.file( "external/bioclim/current/bio11.grd", 
                             package="biomod2"), 
                system.file( "external/bioclim/current/bio12.grd", 
                             package="biomod2"))



 myBiomodData <- BIOMOD_FormatingData(resp.var = myResp,
                             expl.var = myExpl,
                             resp.xy = myRespXY,
                             resp.name = myRespName)

myBiomodOption <- BIOMOD_ModelingOptions()

myBiomodModelOut <- BIOMOD_Modeling( myBiomodData, 
                             models = c('SRE','CTA','RF'), 
                             models.options = myBiomodOption, 
                             NbRunEval=1, 
                             DataSplit=80, 
                             Yweights=NULL, 
                             VarImport=3, 
                             models.eval.meth = c('TSS'),
                             SaveObj = TRUE,
                             rescal.all.models = FALSE,
                             do.full.models = FALSE,
                             modeling.id='test')

myBiomodModelOut_scores <- get_evaluations(myBiomodModelOut)

models_scores_graph(myBiomodModelOut, by = "models" ,
                   metrics = c("ROC","TSS"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get AUC output, you need to specify it as an evaluation method in `BIOMOD_Modeling()`. As you have it, you are only using TSS so that is all it shows as the `Testing.data`.

You can either remove the `models.eval.meth` parameter entirely (this will end up showing Kappa, TSS, and AUC) or specify the methods you want (add ROC as below).

```
myBiomodModelOut <- BIOMOD_Modeling( myBiomodData, 
                                     models = c('SRE','CTA','RF'), 
                                     models.options = myBiomodOption, 
                                     NbRunEval=1, 
                                     DataSplit=80, 
                                     Yweights=NULL, 
                                     VarImport=3, 
                                     models.eval.meth = c('ROC', 'TSS'),
                                     SaveObj = TRUE,
                                     rescal.all.models = FALSE,
                                     do.full.models = FALSE,
                                     modeling.id='test')
```

UPDATE:
If you change `NbRunEval` to 3, it will run 3 evaluation runs for each algorithm. The evaluation metrics will be reflected in the `get_evaluations()` function (see below).

```
myBiomodModelOut <- BIOMOD_Modeling( myBiomodData, 
                                     models = c('SRE','CTA','RF'), 
                                     models.options = myBiomodOption, 
                                     NbRunEval=3, 
                                     DataSplit=80, 
                                     Yweights=NULL, 
                                     VarImport=3,
                                     models.eval.meth = c('ROC', 'TSS'),
                                     SaveObj = TRUE,
                                     rescal.all.models = FALSE,
                                     do.full.models = FALSE,
                                     modeling.id='test')

(myBiomodModelOut_scores <- get_evaluations(myBiomodModelOut))

> , , SRE, RUN1, AllData
> 
>     Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
> ROC        0.876    500      88.636      86.575
> TSS        0.752    495      88.636      86.575
> 
> , , CTA, RUN1, AllData
> 
>     Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
> ROC        0.976    191      94.697      94.521
> TSS        0.892    187      94.697      94.521
> 
> , , RF, RUN1, AllData
> 
>     Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
> ROC        0.989    513      95.455      98.082
> TSS        0.935    515      95.455      98.082
> 
> , , SRE, RUN2, AllData
> 
>     Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
> ROC        0.853    500      85.606      84.932
> TSS        0.705    495      85.606      84.932
> 
> , , CTA, RUN2, AllData
> 
>     Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
> ROC        0.939     94      94.697      92.055
> TSS        0.868     96      94.697      92.055
> 
> , , RF, RUN2, AllData
>
>     Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
> ROC        0.987    351      95.455       95.89
> TSS        0.913    354      95.455       95.89
> 
> , , SRE, RUN3, AllData
> 
>     Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
> ROC        0.872    500      86.364      87.945
> TSS        0.743    495      86.364      87.945
> 
> , , CTA, RUN3, AllData
> 
>     Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
> ROC        0.942    159      90.909      91.233
> TSS        0.821    157      90.909      91.233
> 
> , , RF, RUN3, AllData
> 
>     Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
> ROC        0.986    251      95.455      93.973
> TSS        0.893    202      96.970      92.329
```

You can either access these data directly from the `myBiomodModelOut_scores` array or plot using the function you already have (see below).

```
models_scores_graph(myBiomodModelOut, by = "models" ,
                    metrics = c("ROC","TSS"))
```

[image: Evaluation metrics for each algorithm of biomod2 model]

If you want to use these data in a dataframe format, you can extract the evaluations scores:

```
# note that the values in the output here are different from the above 
# array since I ran it in another R session and didn't set a seed...

(eval.df <- t(data.frame(RUN_1 = myBiomodModelOut_scores[ , 1, , 1, ],
                         RUN_2 = myBiomodModelOut_scores[ , 1, , 2, ],
                         RUN_3 = myBiomodModelOut_scores[ , 1, , 3, ])))
>             ROC   TSS
> RUN_1.SRE 0.853 0.706
> RUN_1.CTA 0.917 0.830
> RUN_1.RF  0.982 0.870
> RUN_2.SRE 0.873 0.747
> RUN_2.CTA 0.960 0.847
> RUN_2.RF  0.982 0.902
> RUN_3.SRE 0.873 0.745
> RUN_3.CTA 0.965 0.872
> RUN_3.RF  0.988 0.918
```

Comment: I am still not getting the output I require. The output that I really want is AUC score for model RF Run 1= .., for RF Run 2 = ..., and so on. Finally, I would like to plot the scores and check the differences in AUC scores per model.

Comment: You only have it set to run 1 evaluation run, hence each model only shows one set of evaluation metrics. You can modify `NbRunEval` to get more runs. The `models_scores_graph()` function works as you have it written in your post and should make a scatter plot with ROC on the x-axis and TSS on the y-axis with each of the points representing a different model algorithm (plus error bars representing the range of evaluation scores across each run). Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I also added a line to convert the rather complicated evaluation array to a data frame with just the ROC and TSS scores for each model and run.

Comment: Thank you so much. The dataframe portion was exactly what I needed. But could you please explain what [ , n, , n', ] means as in RUN_1 = myBiomodModelOut_scores[ , 1, , 1, ]? When I changed the numbers RUN_1 = myBiomodModelOut_scores[ , 1, , 2, ] it changed the RUN value to 2 without any change in the notation as RUN_1.GBM.PA1.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit confusing. I would suggest you look into how R handles indexing of arrays. For this purpose though, you can mess around with the numbers and compare to the original array. The first value (n) of the two in the indexing here, refers to the column from each run, so "1" refers to `testing.data`, "2" refers to `Cutoff`, etc. The second value (n') refers to the run number (in this case, RUN 1). The reason the notation in the dataframe does not change is that I labeled them specifically as "RUN_1", "RUN_2", etc. In this example, there is no PA selection, so that may change indexing.